# Understanding projective space as fibrations of tori over spaces with boundaries

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, toric-varieties

The toric manifold $\mathbb{CP}^1$ can be understood as a circle fibration over an interval $I$, with the circles having zero radius at the boundaries of the interval. How does one generalize this viewpoint to higher-dimensional projective spaces, i.e., $\mathbb{CP}^N$?

Can we interpret, e.g., $\mathbb{CP}^2$ as the fibration of the torus $T^2$ over a square $I^2$ or disk? References would be appreciated.

Comment: The keyword is the Atiyah-Guillemin-Sternberg convexity theorem, see example 9.2 here: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Schmaltz.pdf for the application to projective space.

Comment: If you have the book on toric varieties by Cox, Little, and Schenck, chapter 12 is also a good exposition. Projective toric varieties can be written as stratified torus fibrations over their defining (moment) polytope. For the projective space this is the coordinate simplex.

Comment: This is Delzant's theorem

Comment: The map you want is $[z_0,\ldots,z_n] \mapsto {\left[ |z_0|^2,\ldots,|z_d|^2\right]}{\big/}{\sum_{i=0}^d |z_i|^2}$.

Comment: And while Delzant's theorem is relevant, this is hardly Delzant's theorem!